# how can i get rid of space above the header

Tags: html, css

How can I get rid of the space between the top of the webpage and the header?
This is my code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
        
#Header {
    background-image: url(space.jpg);
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Header">
  <p> Weird Title </p>
</div>

<a href ="practice.html"> Click here </a>
```

I tried margin-top but that doesn't work is there something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hey @Nightowl, do you miss something in the answers? Just wondering why you didn't mark one as accepted. Feel free to leave a comment if there is still something that have to be cleared relating to your question. Regards

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply the `margin-top: 0` rule to the `p` element inside the `#Header` div, as the margin is being created by the `p` element instead of the `div`.

As a tip, you can check these kinds of issues using the developer tools on your browser, selecting an element and checking the `border` / `margin` / `padding` values on the right pane.

```
#Header > p {
    margin-top: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<p>`-element has a default `margin-top` across all major browsers which is `1em`.

You have to **reset this default margin** to achieve the desired result.

```css
#Header > p, /* NEW LINE */
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#Header {
    /*background-image: url(space.jpg); make thing visible for snippet*/
    background: #999; /*make thing visible for snippet*/
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Header">
  <p> TITLE </p>
</div>

<a href ="practice.html"> Click here </a>
```

**NOTE:** A lot of CSS properties have default values. To get rid of this in general you can either do a reset or [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the margin and padding of all elements in the DOM by using the `*` CSS selector as shown in the code snippet below. Also, you only need to specify units in CSS when using non-zero values.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
        
#Header {
    background-image: url(space.jpg);
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Header">
  <p> Weird Title </p>
</div>

<a href ="practice.html"> Click here </a>
```

*Please note that although this is a quick and easy solution, it can provide unnecessary overhead for larger sites, as the browsers rendering agent has to update each element in the document.*

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `margin-top` property to `0` to the correct the spacing.